# Pipe NFC Keybopard to python script on raspbery

Tags: python, linux, nfc, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi 3 with a USB NFC Reader. This Reader is like a keyboard. When reading a Card, the Reader sends the Number followed by a enter of the Card as keyboard input. It registers `/dev/input/event0`. The raspberry has no other keyboard, mice or a monitor. I administer the raspberry over ssh.

I have a python script reading with `input` from the console the number and doing some things depending on the Number.

How do I start the python script on my raspberry getting the input?

I thought about following things, but I unsure which is the best or I miss a good option.

- Can I set the python script a startup script, so Input from the keyboard is send to the script?
- Have to read from the `/dev/input/by-id/xxx` device and decode this in the python script (with something like [python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io))?
- Is there a a other device in `/dev` I can pipe from, getting the text direct?

Answer (score 0):

If found a working solution, but think there exists better solutions. I tried to get a systemd service, starting my script and reading from tty1, but I could not get it working. So my solution currently is:

1. Set up auto login

   I created a `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf` file with the content

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I 38400 linux
   ```

   This is got from https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console
2. Start script at login

   Add at the end of the `.bashrc` the startup of my python script